# Can 'myriad' be used without 'of'

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to write 'myriad something' rather than 'myriad of something' when 'myriade' is used as a noun ? For example;

Juggling work, school runs and a myriad other daily obligations often makes it difficult for people to...

This sentence from an IELTS  workbook.

I looked up Cambridge and Oxford Dictionary and the all examplary sentences were 'myriad of something'

Answer (score 2):

It is far more common to say "myriad of" **when used as a noun**.

> We have a myriad of problems.

The only exception I can find is when it is being used in its original meaning, 10,000.

> The army was organized on a decimal system, up to divisions of 10,000 or myriads [example from [Oxford Languages]](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en)

When used as an adjective "myriad" is used on its own

> They offered no solution for all our myriad problems.

Comment: Myriad can be used an adjective. One may find myriad examples of this.

Comment: I just gave one.

Comment: myriad
adjective   literary
UK  /ˈmɪr.i.əd/ US  /ˈmɪr.i.əd/
 
very large in number, or having great variety:
They offered no solution for all our myriad problems.
There are myriad ways in which global warming can imperil the environment. Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: @MichaelHarvey in this case, it's "a myriad," so "myriad" is being used as a noun. If it was supposed to be an adjective, it would be describing "obligations" and the "a" should be omitted.